# Category redirect in breadcrumbs - bad SEO?

Tags: seo, navigation, breadcrumbs

If I have breadcrumbs like this:

home > products > categoryA > subcategory > product

But the only pages I have is the first products page and the end product page the two categories in the middle are the categories for the product.

If I redirect both the categories to the first products page is this bad for SEO? Or should I redirect the categories to equivalent pages, i.e. categoryA will go to a page with the same name.

By the way I am using wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have pages for Category A and subcategory, why are you making breadcrumb links for it? Breadcrumbs are supposed to make it easier for users to navigate your website. Linking to pages that don't exist achieves the exact opposite of that.

You should remove the unnecessary breadcrumbs, and if you want to show that this product belongs to a category and/or subcategory, do it somewhere else where it won't be confused with a link to page that doesn't exist.

Comment: Because i'm using wordpress the breadcrumbs are automatically using the categories for the page. So it's linking to the actual category pages. So it's either redirect to the base products page, redirect to a new page with the same name as the category, or remove them completely and just have home > products > product

Comment: Why not just leave the category pages as category pages?

Comment: Thanks, John Mueller. I didn't think about making a template for the category and then use that instead.